less memory intensive mechanism (vs .communiciate) for capturing output from a large number of subprocesses?
My use case here is to run a number of python subprocesses, using multiple threads, and capture the output of those commands (which is just a sometimes-quite-large blob of text) into the values of another dict.
The OS I'm running this on is linux, but has a number of customizations: one of which is a pretty aggressive memory watchdog for processes not launched in a specific way (and my python script is not special enough to get around the watchdog...)
When I run "too many" threads and some combination of the subprocesses return "too much" output, the memory watchdog barks and my script gets killed.
I did just enough digging to find that the .communicate method buffers output until the subprocess is done, which certainly aligns with the problems I'm having.  But I haven't been able to find another better way to do this, although it seems like this would be a common enough usecase that maybe I'm missing something REALLY obvious?
import subprocess
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def runShowCommands(cmdTable) -> dict:
    """ return a dictionary of captured output from commands defined in cmdTable. """

    def handle_proc_stdout(handle):
        try: 
            procOutput[handle] = procHandles[handle].communicate(timeout=180)[0].decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:       # naughty process!  
            procHandles[handle].kill()
            procOutput[handle] = f"KILLED: command {handle} timed out and was killed"
   
    procOutput = {}  # dict to store output text from show commands 
    procHandles = {}
    for cmd in cmdTable.keys():
        try:
            procHandles[cmd] = subprocess.Popen(cmdTable[cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            procOutput[cmd] = f"NOT FOUND: command {cmd} was not found?"
    threadpool = ThreadPool(processes=4)
    threadpool.map(handle_proc_stdout, procHandles.keys())
    return procOutput


Consider storing the output in the file system or a database rather than a huge dict.

what's the path of least resistance to use a file system?  It's totally fine for me to dump it all into /tmp, but I don't know how I'd use the subprocess/open/communicate primitives for that?

The easiest approach may be to just dump the output of each call to communicate to an individual file (open'd in w mode) named after some unique ID (which may be derived from cmd or thread ID). Since the file names are distinct from each other, you don't have to worry about locking when writing.
